# Word Wrap bug on Stack Overflow user page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, mobile-web

- Link - [My profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12478531/mayur-fartade)
- Browser - Chrome Version 80.0.3987.163 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Site - Mobile Site
- Device - Redmi 5

[image: Img1]

[image: img2]

Comment: I'm not sure that the mobile site is getting updated any more; you might be better off going to the full site. It's responsive enough(tm).

Comment: Mobile web has been abandoned, yeah. There's a similar, reported bug in the full version (AKA the responsive version) that affects the description. Not sure if that got fixed though